# can't install etherape mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, gnome, sniffing

I'm trying to install etherape on my mac using Homebrew, but I got this error:

```
Lore:etherape-0.9.13 lorenzoferri$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... no
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.1.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for ETHERAPE... configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 libglade-2.0 libgnomeui-2.0) were not met:

No package 'libgnomeui-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ETHERAPE_CFLAGS
and ETHERAPE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

This is the result of brew list:

```
Lore:etherape-0.9.13 lorenzoferri$ brew list
atk         gdk-pixbuf      hadoop          libglade        mahout          pkg-config
cairo           gettext         harfbuzz        libiconv        maven           python
fontconfig      glib            icu4c           libpng          openssl         readline
freetype        gobject-introspection   jpeg            libtiff         pango           sqlite
gdbm            gtk+            libffi          libxml2         pixman          wget
```

and if I try to install libgnomeui:

```
Lore:etherape-0.9.13 lorenzoferri$ brew install libgnomeui
==> Installing libgnomeui from aisipos/homebrew-libgnomeui
Error: No available formula for libiconv (dependency of libgnomeui)
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
```

otherwise, if you can tell me a good alternative to etherape for mac, I would like to see traffic in my network 'cause sometimes my internet go really slow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in homebrew-libgnomeui/libbonobo.rb:

```
depends_on 'libiconv'
```

First of all, libiconv is already provided by OS X so this shouldn't be necessary.

The actual error is due to a cross-tap dependency. The libiconv you installed was from homebrew/dupes, but the above dependency only points brew towards the libgnomeui tap or core. Try testing this out with `brew edit libbonobo` and specify

```
depends_on 'homebrew/dupes/libiconv'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the tap first:

```
$ brew tap aisipos/libgnomeui
```

Then:

```
$ brew edit libbonobo
```

Replace this:

```
depends_on 'libiconv'
```

With this:

```
depends_on 'homebrew/dupes/libiconv'
```

Then run this:

```
$ brew install libgnomeui
```

Or, then just install etherape like this instead of installing the libgnomeui (no need to compile etherape source code):

```
$ brew install etherape
```

Comment: One should also **brew cask install xquartz**

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Lorenzo,

If 'libgnomeui-2.0' is what you need just type this:

```
brew install libgnomeui
```